How do I install wifi drivers for Broadcom adapter in an iMac 7.1?
I am installing Ubuntu Budgie on an iMac 7.1 (mid2007 T7300 Core Duo) and cannot get the WiFi card to work.  I have tried manually changing the driver (as per advice other sites) to no avail.

This question is similar to: Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You didn't provide release details; more accurate advice can often be provided when you provide specific details. Don't forget Ubuntu LTS releases offer kernel stack choice; with flavors like Ubuntu Budgie the ISO used to install sets the default, and this can influence drivers as they're kernel modules (ie. changing kernel stack also changes kernel modules)....  You also didn't specify if you tried the standard documentation (eg. https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting.html or the appropriate page for your unstated release)
